# TextField input won't print to console?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a custom TextField widget in my AddNoteScreen. I don't know why it's not printing the TextField input or how to get it to work. I thought having the TextEditingController was all it needed.. I'm new.. sorry to post so much code I don't know how else to explain.

Here is my custom widget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {

final Widget textFields;

  MyWidget(
    {required this.textFields});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

 TextEditingController notesController = TextEditingController();

  List<TextField> textFields = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textFields.add(_buildTextField());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      height: 300,

      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: ListView(
        children: textFields, 
        ),
    );
  }

  TextField _buildTextField() {
    return TextField(
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefix: Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 10,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: 20,
            minHeight: 10,
            maxHeight: 10,
            maxWidth: 20,
          ),
        ),
        autofocus: true,
        onSubmitted: (_) {
          setState(() {
           textFields.add(_buildTextField());
           notesController.text + ' ';
         });
       }
     );
  }    
}
```

My AddNoteScreen:

```
class AddNoteScreen extends StatefulWidget {

User user;
 AddNoteScreen({
     required this.user,
   });

@override
  State<AddNoteScreen> createState() => _AddNoteScreenState();
}

class _AddNoteScreenState extends State<AddNoteScreen> {

TextEditingController notesController = TextEditingController();
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
bool loading = false;

    @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor:Color (0xFF162242),
        elevation: 0,
      ),

      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      notesController.text = '';
    },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(children: [


Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10),),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: MyWidget(
                  textFields: TextField(
                   style: TextStyle (color:  Color(0xFF192A4F),fontSize: 18,),
                   textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                   controller: notesController,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ),
              ),
              ),

 SizedBox(height: 50,),
              loading ? Center (child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) : Container(
                height: 50,
                
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  
                  
                  onPressed: ()async{
                    
      
                  if (
                    notesController.text.isEmpty)
                    {

                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("All feilds are required")));
      
                    } else {
                      
                      setState(() {
                        loading = true;
                      });
                      
                      await FirestoreService().insertNote(notesController.text,
widget.user.uid);


CollectionReference notes = firestore.collection('notes');
                    QuerySnapshot allResults = await notes.get();
                    allResults.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot result) {
                    print(result.data());
                     });

                      setState(() {
                        loading = false;
                      });

                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                }, child: Text("Add Note", style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                ),style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color (0xFF162242)),       
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
        
      ),
      //color:Color (0xFF162242)
      
                //ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Color (0xFF162242),),
                ),
              ),
            ]),),
            ),
      ),
 );
```

My FirestoreService page:

```
class FirestoreService{

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future insertNote(String notes, String userId)async{
    try{
      await firestore.collection('notes').add({
        "notes":notes,
        "userId":userId
      });
 } catch(e){
 }
  }
}
```

And my NoteModel Screen:

```
class NoteModelEdit {
  String id;
  String notes;
  String userId;

  NoteModelEdit({
    required this.id,
    required this.notes,
    required this.userId
  });

  factory NoteModelEdit.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return NoteModelEdit(
      id: snapshot.id,
      notes: snapshot['notes'],
      userId: snapshot['userId']
      );  
  }
}
```

[image: breakpoint]

[image: breakpoint2]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: run in debug mode and place a stopper in class _AddNoteScreenState at print(result.data()); and check, when code stops on it, hover on it and check which type of data is in it

Comment: how do I place a stopper? I haven't heard of a stopper before

Comment: break point red dot while debugging

Comment: I added a photo

Comment: hover on data and then check

Comment: is <String, dynamic> what you're looking for? added a photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are storing an empty note, which is the reason why the result from the database is empty.

This line:

```
if (notesController.text.isNotEmpty) // show error message
```

should become this:

```
if (notesController.text.isEmpty) // show error message
```

Also, this should probably change, too:

```
// This does nothing:
new TextEditingController().clear();

// To clear the controller:
notesController.text = '';
```

**UPDATE**

Change your code as follows to test if something
gets written into the database. Once this works, figure out how to use MyWidget correctly, as there are issues in there, too.

```
// OLD CODE

child: MyWidget(
  textFields: TextField(
    style: TextStyle (color:  Color(0xFF192A4F),fontSize: 18,),
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
    controller: notesController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
    ),
    ),
),

// NEW CODE

child: TextField(
    style: TextStyle (color:  Color(0xFF192A4F),fontSize: 18,),
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
    controller: notesController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
    ),
),
```

I suggest to always only change small parts of code and ensure that your code works at each small step. Do not make too many changes at once.

Comment: if I change it to isEmpty I get the SnackBar message "All fields are required"

Comment: @LeenaMarie Yes, as usually one does not want to save empty text. If you enter some text in the TextField,, does the text get saved?

Comment: @LeenaMarie Also, your code is getting data and printing it from Firebase, before the data is stored in Firebase. Getting data and printing it should happen after saving it. Otherwise, the result is misleading.

Comment: agreed and the text doesn't get saved

Comment: does CollectionReference bit belong after ```await FirestoreService().insertNote```?

Comment: @LeenaMarie Yes, because this reference is used to find out if the data has been written successfully. Also, check your Firebase Console manually for any data entries. Click on your project, then on Firestore on the left and check the data yourself: https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: okay, thanks and in my Firebase console is shows "" every attempt

Comment: @LeenaMarie  The empty entries stem basically from the former line `notesController.text.isNotEmpty`.  You would need to update your current code here, so people can spot the problem. As there is probably a combination of problems involved.

Comment: right, thank you Dabbel. for today and yesterday!

Comment: @LeenaMarie See the updated answer, this should at least get you some database entries.